# Why isn't my css being applied to my checkbox when checked, but only when rendered by razor?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I took the following HTML:

```
<div class="small-6 columns">
    <input id="temp-id-2" class="replace-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
    <label for="temp-id-2" class="checkbox-label">Taxable?</label>
</div>
```

And implemented it in razor:

```
<div class="small-6 columns">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.InventoryItem.Taxable, new { @class="replace-checkbox", id="temp-id-2" })
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.InventoryItem.Taxable, new { @class="checkbox-label", @for="temp-id-2" })
</div>
```

It is getting rendered like this:

```
<div class="small-6 columns">
    <input checked="checked" class="replace-checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Taxable field is required." id="temp-id-2" name="InventoryItem.Taxable" type="checkbox" value="true" />
    <input name="InventoryItem.Taxable" type="hidden" value="false" />
    <label for="temp-id-2" class="checkbox-label">Taxable?</label>
</div>
```

And I have the following css:

```
form.app-form label.checkbox-label { 
    display: block; 
    visibility: visible; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    color: #5c5c5c; 
    padding: 9px 10px; 
    padding-left: 40px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: 10px center; 
    background-image: url("../images/field-check-inactive-10.png"); 
    background-position: right center; padding-left: 10px; 
}

form.app-form .replace-checkbox { 
    position: absolute; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
    height: 1px; 
    width: 1px; 
    margin: -1px; 
    padding: 0; 
    border: 0; }
form.app-form .replace-checkbox:checked + label.checkbox-label { 
    padding-left: 40px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: 10px center; 
    background-image: url("../images/field-check-10.png"); 
    background-position: right center; 
    padding-left: 10px; 
}
```

When I run the plain HTML, I am able to check the checkbox and it changes from a greyed out check mark to a darkened in check mark. However, when I render it in razor, the checked state does not change. I noticed that the page is still detected that it is being checked because I can see the values change when I submit the form, but the css doesn't seem to get applied when it is in the checked state. I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: your css specifies that the check box is in a form tag with class app-form.  look at your rendered html.  does that form tag exist on the page?

Comment: Yeah, its there, the app-form class is applied and the checkbox is inside of the form

Comment: if you remove the form requirement does the styling work?  if you need something to make it more specific maybe you can use the div instead of the form.

Comment: Negative. If I remove the form requirement from all 3 selectors, the control disappears completely. I tried removing them one by one, but there was no effect.

Comment: Do you think the hidden field is messing up the selector??

Comment: Actually, I just confirmed that. The hidden field is messing up the selector. When I remove the hidden field, it works. Good grief razor fail

Comment: very glad you figured it out :)

Comment: Thank you. I was concentrating on the contents of the css and the elements themselves when i should have been looking closer at the selectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem is with how MVC uses hidden fields to post data back to the controller. In this chunk:

```
<div class="small-6 columns">
    <input checked="checked" class="replace-checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Taxable field is required." id="temp-id-2" name="InventoryItem.Taxable" type="checkbox" value="true" />
    <input name="InventoryItem.Taxable" type="hidden" value="false" />
    <label for="temp-id-2" class="checkbox-label">Taxable?</label>
</div>
```

It added the hidden field element which broke the css selector `form.app-form .replace-checkbox:checked + label.checkbox-label` which selects the label immediately following the checkbox. Since it no longer immediate follows the checkbox, it never gets applied.

My fix (for now) for this was to change the `+` to a `~`